# AWS EC2 volume names different from console and fdisk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am checking mapped volumes inside an ec2-instance (centos-7). I have attached two 500 GB volumes to an ec2 instance, but I could not find which one mapped which disk name.

fdisk disk name shows `/dev/nvme3n1 and /dev/nvme5n1` but aws console shows `/dev/sde /dev/sdd`

`fdisk -l` and `aws ec2 describe-volumes ..` device_names are different. Is there a way to find which volume mapped to which device name?

`fdisk -l`

```
[root@ip-192-168-66-22 deploy]# fdisk -l



Disk /dev/nvme3n1: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/nvme5n1: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

AWS client result

`aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)`

```
{
            "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1a",
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2021-10-06T14:24:28.000Z",
                    "InstanceId": "i-sss",
                    "VolumeId": "vol-ss",
                    "State": "attached",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                    "Device": "/dev/sde"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Disk1",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "Encrypted": false,
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "VolumeId": "vol-ss",
            "State": "in-use",
            "Iops": 1500,
            "SnapshotId": "",
            "CreateTime": "2021-10-06T14:24:28.872Z",
            "Size": 500
        },
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1a",
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2021-10-06T14:24:28.000Z",
                    "InstanceId": "i-ss",
                    "VolumeId": "vol-yy",
                    "State": "attached",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                    "Device": "/dev/sdd"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Disk-2",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "Encrypted": false,
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "VolumeId": "vol-yy",
            "State": "in-use",
            "Iops": 1500,
            "SnapshotId": "",
            "CreateTime": "2021-10-06T14:24:28.963Z",
            "Size": 500
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase one of the volumes with 1 GB to differentiate between the two volumes